# how upload images and videos to specific folder like wp-content\uploads\folder-name

Tags: uploads

I used the basic PHP code to upload files like JPG, PNG and so on.
To improve, I want to use WordPress secure and built-in functions and classes. I found the excellent `wp_handle_upload ()` function which works great.

The only problem is that I can not move the uploaded file to the desired folder.
Can anyone help me please?
for example the location folder is wp-content\uploads\folder-name

Answer (score -1):

i do that with some line of code

add this to function.php to change the uploaded file dir

```
// change dir for anomaly images
function example_Dir( $param ){
    $param['path'] = '/home/yoursite/domains/yoursite.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/example';
    $param['url'] = ' https://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/example';
    return $param;
}
```

here is the form :

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

then what PHP code you need is

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
$file = $_FILES['file'];
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'example_Dir');
    $Result = wp_handle_upload($file  , $upload_overrides);
    remove_filter('upload_dir' , 'example_Dir');
}
```

done!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.